# PHP-Mysqli update query trouble

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm not that great at coding and I got stuck on maybe a fairly easy query, I would appreciate all the help, I'm using mysqli. here is my php-code:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['email_adres'])){
        $email_adres = trim($_POST['email_adres']);
        $score = 1;
        if(!empty($email_adres)) {
            $insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE gebruiker SET score WHERE email_adres = $email_adres VALUES(?)");
            $insert->bind_param('s',$score);
            if($insert->execute()){
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: well there you go; non-object. could be anything. check for errors on PHP/MySQL sides of things.

Comment: and your query is wayyyy off `WHERE email_adres = $email_adres VALUES(?)`. This calls for an MySQL 101 tutorial. and `bind_param('s'` and trying to bind an integer.

Comment: Your query has a syntax error. Should be `UPDATE gebruiker SET score = ? WHERE email_adres = ?`. You should also bind your `$email_adre` -> `$insert->bind_param('is',$score, $email_adre);`

Comment: I think you're trying to do this: `$insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE gebruiker SET score = ? WHERE email_adres = ?"); $insert->bind_param('ss',$score, $email_adres);` Edit: After looking at your variable `$insert`, I think you're confused between `UPDATE` and `INSERT` query.

Comment: I really have to say this. Bad questions often attract bad answers (given so far). So, ask them below.

Comment: like mentioned before your prepare statement is invalid in that case `$db->prepare(...` will return `false` you can check  [manual](http://php.net/manual/pl/pdo.prepare.php) for possible return values. BTW it's a good practice to setup PDO to raise exception when something fails [check manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)

Comment: @manRo He's using mysqli, not PDO.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for update query is like this :

```
Update {table_name} SET {fieldname} = {value} WHERE {condition}
```

So, our query should be like this

```
UPDATE gebruiker SET score = ? WHERE email_adres = ?
```

Check below code :

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['email_adres'])){
        $email_adres = trim($_POST['email_adres']);
        $score = 1;
        if(!empty($email_adres)) {
            $insert = $db->prepare("UPDATE gebruiker SET score = ? WHERE email_adres = ?");
            $insert->bind_param('is',$score,$email_adres);
            if($insert->execute()){
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so care to explain why their code is failing them? so many low-quality answers these days, it's not funny.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong `UPDATE` statement. It should be something like this:

```
UPDATE gebruiker SET score = ? WHERE email_adres = $email_adres
```

Comment: `$email_adres` needs to be in quotes. But it would be better to use a parameter.